# Использование функций в конструкторе

Tags: javascript, ооп, объекты, конструктор

Есть конструктор:

```
function Example(variable) {
        this.name = variable;
        this.test = function() {
            return 'вперед';
        }
    }

    let foo = new Example('Вася');
```

Почему свойству `test` не присваевается значение `вперед`?

Comment: Объясните, почему Вы думаете, что это должно произойти, и откуда возьмется значение `2`, если его нет в коде?

Comment: @Igor это опечатка, я поправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Капитан Очевидность глаголит: потому что свойству `test` присваивается не `вперёд`, а функция.

Если нужно возвратить из функции значение и уже его присвоить, то нужно так:

```js
function Example(variable) {
  this.name = variable;
  this.test = function() {
    return 'вперед';
  }(); // Используем самовызывающиеся функции и присвоим уже результат
       // Правда зачем функция, если конструктор и сам функция? Вычисляйте в нём что надо и присваивайте только когда будет надо
}

let foo = new Example('Вася');
```

Comment: Это была опечатка.

Comment: @brachkoff, уже увидел. Тоже обновил ответ.

Comment: А. Мне кажется я совсем затупил и забыл о том что есть методы. Мда. А можно каким либо образом присвоить свойству значение которое возвращает функция а не саму функцию?

Comment: @brachkoff, обновил.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function Example(variable) {
  this.name = variable;
  this.test = function() {
    return 'Вперед, ' + variable + '!';
  }()
}

let foo = new Example('Вася');
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: Такой вариант работает, но если нам потребуется использовать в условии `variable` все сломается.

Comment: @brachkoff Нет, не сломается.

Comment: Хмм, работает. А почему когда мы ссылаемся на `this.name` не работает?

Comment: А, я понял потому что this будет ссылаться на объект нашей функции, а не функции конструктора.

Comment: Если не так - поправьте

Comment: @brachkoff Почти. Когда вызывается анонимная функция, это происходит **не** в контексте создаваемого объекта.

Comment: В таком случае как сослался на значение `this.name`?

Comment: @brachkoff Не понял, переформулируйте.

Comment: Допустим в строке с `return` я захочу использовать значение из `this.name`. Как мне на него сослаться?

Comment: @brachkoff Никак. Его там нет.